# Power BI: ranking a table based on a condition

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop

I have a dashboard in Power BI that looks like this:

| Name | Specified Activity | Level | Activity Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Anna | Basketball | 2 | Sports |
| Anna | Volleyball | 3 | Sports |
| Julie | Basketball | 1 | Sports |
| Julie | Tennis | 2 | Sports |
| Julie | Guitar | 4 | Instrument |
| Julie | Piano | 5 | Instrument |

And I would like to group it to look like this:

| Ordered Number | Name | Specified Activity | Level | Activity Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Anna | Basketball | 2 | Sports |
| 1 | Anna | Volleyball | 3 | Sports |
| 2 | Julie | Basketball | 1 | Sports |
| 2 | Julie | Tennis | 2 | Sports |
| 3 | Julie | Guitar | 4 | Instrument |
| 3 | Julie | Piano | 5 | Instrument |

To clarify, if the name and activity group are the same, they should have the same ranking number. If the next row has a different name or activity group, the number should become higher for +1. So it should be a ranked column but with a condition. I tried using the RANKX function, but I am not sure how to add a condition that I need.

I earlier asked for this issue to be solved more complexly (with a dropdown), but nobody up to this moment knows how to solve it, so I assumed that perhaps it is not even possible to add a partial dropdown, so I changed the dropdown with a rank.

Comment: Post your measure(s). Have you read the documentation on RANKX? Reza Rad has articles about it on his website, radacad.com (one source).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Rank, it is more of an incremental count/index.

This is fairly easily done in PowerQuery with:

1. Select `Name` and `Activity Group` columns, then do a `Group by` with Operation `All rows`.
2. Add an Index column starting at 1.
3. Expand the table column from step 1 with `Specified Activity` and `Level` columns.

Here's the PQ for the above:

```
let
  Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WcszLS1TSUXJKLM5OLUlKzMkBcoyAOLggv6ikWClWB64kLD8nJ7USqsQYVYlXaU5mKroxhtjVhKTm5WUWY1oDk3cvzSxJLAIyTIDYM6+4pKg0NzWvBEVNQGZiXj6QNkVTEgsA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Name = _t, #"Specified Activity" = _t, Level = _t, #"Activity Group" = _t]),
  #"Grouped rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Name", "Activity Group"}, {{"Rows", each _, type nullable table[Name = nullable text, #"Specified Activity" = nullable text, Level = nullable text, #"Activity Group" = nullable text]}}),
  #"Added index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Grouped rows", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
  #"Expanded Rows" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added index", "Rows", {"Specified Activity", "Level"}, {"Specified Activity", "Level"}) 
in
  #"Expanded Rows"
```

---

Alternatively, if you need to do it in DAX, then create a Calculated Column on your table with:

```
Ordered Number = 
  COUNTROWS(
    SUMMARIZE(
      FILTER(
        'YourTable',
        [Name] & "_" & [Activity Group] <= EARLIER([Name]) & "_" & EARLIER([Activity Group])
      ),
      [Name],
      [Activity Group]
    )
  )
```